# Passport.js: how to protect ALL routes?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I followed the documentation for passport.js with passport-local: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/

When I send my users to `/login` they are authenticated, but nowhere in that document can I find how to **authorise** my users.

I've tried this, but that gives me a `bad request`:

```
router.get('/somepage', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next) {

});
```

I'm looking for way to protect all my pages at once. I'm working with Express 4.16 and use different route files to split up my routes.

Sam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `middleware` with a small trick to switch between strategies

example:

```
const allowUrl = ['public', 'nonprivate','home'];


const authenticationMiddleware = (whiteList =[]) => (req, res, next) => {
    if(whiteList.includes(req.baseUrl)) {
      next();
    }

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/');
}


app = express();
app.use(passort.initialize());
app.use(authenticationMiddleware(allowUrl));
app.use(apiRouter);


app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('hello internet');
```

Comment: Why would you make a function that returns a function?

Comment: .find(req.baseUrl) - that's not a valid call for find() + res.redirect('/') could end up with infinite loop

Comment: @AndrejK the api might change at this time (I'm not sure :D), so I updated the array to use `includes` instead of `find`. Nice caught thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can add your middleware code like below

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
   //your next function 
});
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  // do any checks you want to in here

  // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
  // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
  if (req.user.authenticated)
      return next();

  // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Would the '/' (root iirc) route, in this case, be the route that contains the login page?

Answer (score 2):

As I wanted ALL routes (except for login routes off course) to pass authorization, I solved it as follows:

```
var ensureAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    else res.redirect('/login')
}

// usersRouter contains all open routes like '/login':
app.use('/', usersRouter);

// From here on, all routes need authorization:
app.use(ensureAuthenticated);

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/foo', fooRouter);
app.use('/api/bar', barRouter);
```

Comment: IMHO my solution is better, since you can add `ensureAuthenticated` function anywhere, do not care about the position of protected / unprotected api (before or after middleware). It was controlled by the  `allowUrl` array as my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "but nowhere in that document can I find how to authorise my users". Passportjs won't authorize any user. It is an authentication middleware. Authorization is different from authentication.

I think you are looking for application level middleware. You have to use app.use to make authentication work for each request to the server.
You can read more about it here. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application